# Virtual box (5.x) add a USB bzw. serial device

Tags: ubuntu, serialization, usb, ros

I installed ubuntu 14.04 LTS within oracle box version 5.1.8. In this system I installed Ros indigo. I then want to connect this pc to a roomba 521 (vaccuum cleaner with an open interface for controlling) via USB to MIN DIN cable. Next I launch a simple launch file to send some commands to the Roomba (This did not work, if I do this within oracle box).

If I type lsusb in a terminal I see:
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0403:6001 Future Technology Devices International, Ltd FT232 USB-Serial (UART) IC

This is the Port or USB connection I want to use. Now my question:

(1) Do I have to setup a Serial or USB connection for the communication?

In case of a USB connection I already did the following:
1. Adding the USB device to the USB filters.
2. I also tried to FIX group permissions and installed:
gnome-system-tools (via Software Center)
-> then I went to users -> vboxfs and selected the USER
(as described in [this tutorial](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/05/install-users-groups-management-tool-ubuntu1404/))
3. I also installed virtual box guest editions

Adjusting a serial connection did not work for me yet. As virtual box is always giving me the following error after changing the Settings of my Ubuntu 14.04 machine as described [here Takkat answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16586/how-to-access-serial-ubuntu-host-serial-port-on-virtualbox-guest-os).

Failed to open host device 'dev\ttyS0' (VERR_PATH_NOT_FOUND).

I kind of cannot solve this error as even if I type dev**/**ttyS0 in the serial settings vm box is always changing it to ****. Does that even matter?

Additional Links:
http://answers.ros.org/question/243609/boostexception_detailclone_impl/

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved the error when following this instruction here:

http://jjmilburn.github.io/2016/04/04/ttyUSB-to-vagrant-virtualbox/